# Change form label font to bold using its tag

Tags: vba, tags, label, ms-word

I have a form in Word VBA with multiple labels. When clicking on a button I want to change a label font to bold by calling on it's tag using a string.

Example:

```
Private Sub changeFontButton_Click()
    Dim tagStr as String
    tagStr = "tag1"

    labelWithTagName(tagStr)
    labelWithTagName.Font.Bold=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The MSForms object model does not support using tag values as an index for addressing the control. You can only do this using the `Name` property:

```
Me.Controls("NameOfLabel").Font.Bold = True
```

If you really want/need to use the tag property then you have to loop the controls on the form

```
Dim ctl As MSForms.control
Dim lbl As MSForms.Label

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.Tag = "rs" Then
        Set lbl = ctl
        lbl.Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next
```